# Android Studio Crash Debug log opens another class with same name from different module

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug, android-studio-dolphin

I am using 'Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1'.
From the crash logs on Android Studio logcat when I select to open the link to the class/line where the crash occurred it opens another class with the same name but from a different module.

In my app, I have different modules with different variants/flavors as the functionality is similar/same for other modules too, so it has the same structure and same name of the classes.